# How to change code page (language driver) of Paradox db file

Tags: c#, oledb, codepages, cyrillic, paradox

When I create paradox db file, the file is created with default codepage 437 (OEM United States).
But I need 1252 (Cyrillic (Windows)) codepage.
Is it possible to change the codepage or is it possible to create one with different codepage.

I use .Net OleDB provider to work with Paradox. Code is below:

```
OleDbConnection ole_conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Paradox 7.x;Data Source=" + FileName);
ole_conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE testdb.DB (ID INTEGER, FULLNAME VARCHAR(50));", ole_conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: According to this, you could do it with the microsoft paradox driver instead (CollationSequence parameter), however, i'm not sure if that is what you are looking for: http://www.connectionstrings.com/paradox/ , btw, is it a race with this topic? :) http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/857104/How-to-change-codepage-of-Paradox-db-file

Comment: Yes, i wrote the codeproject topic.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with .Net, which you are using. But in the original Paradox you could set the codepage - which would usually be done once and would remain for the application. Then tables would be created with that code page. Maybe there is a setting in .Net similar to that.